# Load image from firebase storage/database to cardview using firebaserecyclerview

Tags: android, image, firebase, picasso, android-glide

In my `populateViewHolder`, I have tried using both glide and picasso to load my image into cardview. For some reason, Picasso works, but Glide does not.

I really want to implement Glide into my code instead of Picasso. Any ideas how to solve this?

The `chat.getImage_path()`, gets a url string from firebase database, which corresponds to the image url in firebase storage.

```
mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ImageInformation, ImageHolder>(
                ImageInformation.class,
                R.layout.card_item_feed,
                ImageHolder.class,
                mDatabase) {

            @Override
            public void populateViewHolder(ImageHolder holder, ImageInformation chat, int position) {

                holder.image_desc.setText(chat.getImageDesc());
                holder.date.setText(chat.getDate_created());
                //Glide.with(Feed.this).load(chat.getImage_path()).into(holder.feed_image);
                Picasso.with(getContext()).load(chat.getImage_path()).into(holder.feed_image);
                holder.tag.setText(chat.getTags());
            }
        };
        rv.setAdapter(mFirebaseAdapter);
```

Comment: what u mean by saying glide does not work?

Comment: The image does not load when I use glide. But it loads when I use picasso. @mehdiakbarian

Comment: set chat.getImage_path().trim() as url in glide

Comment: still not working @mehdiakbarian

Comment: did u try use getContext() instead of Feed.this for Glide?

Comment: yes. doesn't work